# Bootstrap Datetimepicker disappears on second click

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I have an Input control on my webform on which I am using bootstarp datetimepicker. The datetimepicker works perfectly when I click for the first time on the Input control. But if I click again on the input control, Datetimepicker disappears. I have click somewhere else on the webform and then click again on input control to show it. I am not able to find what is problem. Any kind of help is highly appreciated.
I hope my explanation is not confusing!

I have checked several question here on stackoverflow but none of them are working for me. I tried checking in datetimepicker documentation also but couldn't find anything or maybe I was not able to understand it properly.

HTML Code:

```
<div>
<div class="input-group date form_date" id="dt_1" data-date="" data-date-format="yyyy-mm-dd" data-link-field="dtp_input2" data-link-format="yyyy-mm-dd" style="width:inherit;">
<input class="form-control" type="text" value="" readonly="true" id="date1" style="width:inherit;" />
<span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></span>
</div>                                        
</div>
```

Jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $('.form_date').datetimepicker({
        //language:  'fr',
        weekStart: 1,
        //todayBtn:  1, 
        autoclose: 1,
        todayHighlight: 1,
        startView: 2,
        minView: 2,          
        forceParse: 0
        });            
</script>
```

Bootstrap scripts:

```
<link href="../Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="../date/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="../date/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js"></script>
```

Expected result is that Datetimepicker should not disappear on second click. It should only disappear if date selected or if clicked somewhere outside the control.
Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: Try to create a minimal reproducible example on jsFiddle or similar and update your question with a link to it.

Comment: What bootstrap-datetimepicker do you use? It seems there are a few different ones. If it's eonasdan's it also needs Moment.js.

Comment: @LazarMomcilovic I am trying to create a fiddle but in jsFiddle date-time picker is not working

Comment: @Hexronimo How to check type I am not able find it?

Comment: Where did you download it? When I search for bootstrap-datatimepicker first founded site is eonasdan, then go some others. Also, I use bootstrap-datapicker (cus I don't need time) and it works well. But anyway, to recreate your example and check what may be wrong we need to know what datatimepicker you use.

Comment: @Hexronimo sorry for the late reply. I checked just now it is eonasdan, i have moment.js also within the project but still it is showing same error. i'll try with only bootstrap-datepicker.